# How can I efficiently convert the output of one KDB function into three table columns?

Tags: kdb

I have a function that takes as input some of the values in a table and returns a tuple if you will - three separate return values, which I want to transpose into the output of a query. Here's a simplified example of what I want to achieve:

```
multiplier:{(x*2;x*3;x*3)};
select twoX:multiplier[price][0]; threeX:multiplier[price][1]; fourX:multiplier[price][2] from data;
```

The above basically works (I think I've got the syntax right for the simplified example - if not then hopefully my intention is clear), but is inefficient because I'm calling the function three times and throwing away most of the output each time. I want to rewrite the query to only call the function once, and I'm struggling.

### Update

I think I missed a crucial piece of information in my explanation of the problem which affects the outcome - I need to get other data in the query alongside the output of my function. Here's a hopefully more realistic example:

```
multiplier:{(x*2;x*3;x*4)};
select average:avg price, total:sum price, twoX:multiplier[sum price][0]; threeX:multiplier[sum price][1]; fourX:multiplier[sum price][2] by category from data;
```

I'll have a go at adapting your answers to fit this requirement anyway, and apologies for missing this bit of information. The real function if a proprietary and fairly complex algorithm and the real query has about 30 output columns, hence the attempt at simplifying the example :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just looking for the results themselves you can extract (exec) as lists, create dictionary and then flip the dictionary into a table:

```
q)exec flip`twoX`threeX`fourX!multiplier[price] from ([]price:til 10)
twoX threeX fourX
-----------------
0    0      0
2    3      4
4    6      8
6    9      12
8    12     16
10   15     20
12   18     24
14   21     28
16   24     32
18   27     36
```

If you need other columns from the original table too then its trickier but you could join the tables sideways using `,'`

```
q)t:([]price:til 10)
q)t,'exec flip`twoX`threeX`fourX!multiplier[price] from t
```

Comment: As mentioned in my update I need to pull out additional column data in my query (apologies for leaving that out of my definition of the problem) and adding price (for example) to the left of the `flip` prevents the flip from creating columns as shown in your output.

Comment: Ah my bad, I missed that you'd updated the answer. Yep, this works perfectly, thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

An apply `@` can also achieve what you want. Here `data` is just a table with 10 random prices. `@` is then used to apply the `multiplier` function to the `price` column while also assigning a column name to each of the three resulting lists:

```
q)data:([] price:10?100)
q)multiplier:{(x*2;x*3;x*3)}
q)@[data;`twoX`threeX`fourX;:;multiplier data`price]
price twoX threeX fourX
-----------------------
80    160  240    240
24    48   72     72
41    82   123    123
0     0    0      0
81    162  243    243
10    20   30     30
36    72   108    108
36    72   108    108
16    32   48     48
17    34   51     51
```

Comment: This seems closer to what I'm shooting for because the output includes the price, but thinking about it I'm kinda locked into using a select statement because I have code all over the place that's already using select syntax that's currently just pulling a single value out of the algorithm. The change I'm introducing is for the algorithm to return a second and third value which I need to map into columns, but it'd actually be easier to refactor the algorithm into three algorithms than change every point of consumption.